# return type problem

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I want with this code to check two conditions:

- if I have information but the family is empty display the error message of the label.
- If null information display again the same error message
  if not, use the save method (public static ID saveprb) but I have this error

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void saveprb()  .
>
> Missing return statement required return type: String

How can I fix this .

```apex
public static String check(Id RecordTypeId) {
    List<check__c> CheckInfo = [SELECT id ,name, Family__c 
                                FROM check__c 
                                WHERE Account__r.id =:RecordTypeId  ]; 
    for (check__c check: CheckInfo ) { 
        String s2 =  System.Label.label1    ; 
        if(CheckInfo .size() < 0) {
            return s2; 
        } else if(CheckInfo .size() > 0 || check.Family__c == null ) {
            return s2; 
        } else{ 
            saveprb(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you also include the code for saveprb()? Is it in the same class?

Comment: @GuyClairbois , yes it is in the same class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those cases where the errors correctly tell you what the issues are.

---

###### Issue 1

```
public static String check(Id RecordTypeId)
              ^^^^^^
```

`String` here in the method signature indicates that this method returns a `String` to the code that calls it. Outside of an exception, if you attempt to end/exit the method without a `return` statement that includes a string* (either a literal or a `String` variable), then the compiler will complain with the following:

> Missing return statement required return type: String

As *Nagendra Singh* pointed out, in this conditional section of your code...

```apex
} else { 
    saveprb(); 
}
```

...you are trying to end/exit the method without returning a `String`.

Even if `saveprb()` returns a `String`, you are not then returning that from within this `check()` method.

If it did return a `String`, you would probably just be able to change that one line to ...

```apex
} else { 
    return saveprb(); 
}
```

...to make it work.

---

###### Issue 2

You did not include the code for `saveprb()` which *Guy Clairbois* requested in his comment under your question, so we do not know exactly what it does. But from this error...

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void saveprb()

...we can only guess that either

- The method is not visible, or
- The method is expecting a parameter that you are not passing in.

You told *Guy* that the method is visible, so we will assume that is not the issue.

That leaves us - again since you have not included the `saveprb()` code (or at least its signature) - with assuming that it is expecting one or more parameters.

```
public static Id saveprb(?are_there_one_or_more_parameters_here?)
```

If there are parameters in the method signature, you cannot just call `saveprb()` - you have to include the appropriate expected arguments (in the correct order) inside the `()` of `saveprb()`.

---

###### Additional Issues

- The size of your `CheckInfo` List will never be less than zero.  It might be zero, but never less.

  *(And if somehow it could be less than zero, it would never reach that line of code since that check on the size of your List is occurring within the loop in which you are iterating over said List.)*
- If you `return` in the middle of a `for` loop when there is more than one object in the List you are iterating over, you'll never process anything after the first object in the List.

Comment: thank you for all this information , I changed the return , and for the method: ` saveprb` it have a parameters , `   public static ID saveprb(Id Accountid,Id last, string Perioddate, Id accountl, boolean first  ) {`

Comment: Then there is your answer: You are calling `saveprb()` without passing in the Account Id, whatever Id type that "last" is, the period date, etc.  You need to include all of that when you call that method. ... I do not mean to offend, but it seems that you are in a little over your head, because method signatures/parameters are part of the basics of programming in almost any language - not just Apex. If this is something that you are required to do & cannot give this to another person, then you should start here: trailhead.salesforce.com - sign up is free - and do the Developer Beginner trail.

Comment: thank you for your help and also for your advice .

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
    else{
        saveprb();
    }
```

If it goes to this `else` you don't have a return here. Which means if the code goes here it wont be able to return.

Please add a return type.

If `saveprb` returns an ID. Change that to String, and use `Database` class to return a proper error message so that you can return it like this.

Then you can add a return type.

```
    } else{
        return saveprb();
    }
```

Comment: even if I changed the return type of the method saveprb , I have the same problem

Comment: why does saveprb return anything? If you don't need it to return anything, make it a void.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```apex
public static String check(Id RecordTypeId) {
     List<check__c> CheckInfo = [SELECT id ,name, Family__c FROM check__c WHERE Account__r.id =:RecordTypeId  ]; 
    for (check__c check: CheckInfo ) { 
        String s2 =  System.Label.label1    ; 
        if(CheckInfo .size() < 0) {
            return s2; 
        } else if(CheckInfo .size() > 0 || check.Family__c == null ) {
            return s2; 
        } else { 
            String str = saveprb();
        if(str.isEmpty()){
            return System.debug('Error message 1');
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```